# SQL Transaction Attribution

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I need to extract the total number of users who have transacted based on varying lookback windows.

To start off with, I have a table like this:

```
user_id     date        action
1           2018/01/01  click
3           2018/01/01  view
5           2018/01/01  click
1           2018/01/02  view
1           2018/01/02  view
3           2018/01/03  click
2           2018/01/05  click
1           2018/01/05  transact
3           2018/01/05  transact
2           2018/01/06  view
1           2018/01/06  click
3           2018/01/06  view
2           2018/01/08  transact
2           2018/01/08  click
1           2018/01/08  click
1           2018/01/09  click
4           2018/01/09  click
3           2018/01/12  view
4           2018/01/12  transact
3           2018/01/13  view
5           2018/01/13  transact
4           2018/01/15  view
5           2018/01/15  click
4           2018/01/16  view
2           2018/01/17  transact
5           2018/01/18  click
```

From here, I imagine that I need to extract the last non-transact date and action that occurred before the transact action and the number of days since the previous action. So then the table would look something like this:

```
user_id     date        action      prevdate_nontrans       prev_nontrans_action        days_since
1           2018/01/01  click           
3           2018/01/01  view            
5           2018/01/01  click           
1           2018/01/02  view            
1           2018/01/02  view            
3           2018/01/03  click           
2           2018/01/04  click           
1           2018/01/05  transact    2/01/2018               view                        3
3           2018/01/05  transact    3/01/2018               click                       2
2           2018/01/06  view            
1           2018/01/06  click           
3           2018/01/06  view            
2           2018/01/08  transact    5/01/2018               click                       3
2           2018/01/08  click           
1           2018/01/08  click           
1           2018/01/09  click           
4           2018/01/09  click           
3           2018/01/12  view            
4           2018/01/12  transact    9/01/2018               click                       3
3           2018/01/13  view            
5           2018/01/13  transact    1/01/2018               click                       12
4           2018/01/15  view            
5           2018/01/15  click           
4           2018/01/16  view            
2           2018/01/17  transact    8/01/2018               click                       9
5           2018/01/18  click
```

Using this, I'm hoping to build out a table that shows me the weekly breakdown of the total number of users per week who did any non-transaction action and the number of people who transacted based on different lookback windows. For example:

```
date (weekly)       total   1-day lookback  2-day lookback  3-day lookback
1/01/2018           4       0               1               3
8/01/2018           5       0               0               1
15/01/2018          3       0               0               0
```

Based on week commencing January 1, user ids 1,2,3 and 5 did a non-transaction action resulting to a total of 4. Based on a 1-day lookback of transactions, no users were found. Based on a 2-day lookback, user id 3 was found resulting to 1 on the table. Based on a 3-day lookback, user id 3,1 and 2 were found resulting to 3 on the table.

The count under the lookback columns would be based on when the non-transaction action occurred - explaining why user id 2's transaction on January 8 was attributed to the week of January 1st (3-day lookback).

For reference, I'm building the tables using Athena. Slicing the data further based on the types of actions will eventually matter so if you have any thoughts on that, that would be great as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used below Query to achieve your result but date column datatype must be DATETIME and action column should be INT with reference of action_id(action table) to get better performance.

```
CREATE TABLE user_action(user_id BIGINT, Date DATE, action VARCHAR(100)); 

INSERT INTO user_action(user_id, Date, action)
VALUES
(1,'2018/01/01', 'click'),
(3,'2018/01/01',  'view'),
(5,'2018/01/01',  'click'),
(1,'2018/01/02',  'view'),
(1,'2018/01/02',  'view'),
(3,'2018/01/03',  'click'),
(2,'2018/01/05',  'click'),
(1,'2018/01/05',  'transact'),
(3,'2018/01/05',  'transact'),
(2,'2018/01/06',  'view'),
(1,'2018/01/06',  'click'),
(3,'2018/01/06',  'view'),
(2,'2018/01/08',  'transact'),
(2,'2018/01/08',  'click'),
(1,'2018/01/08',  'click'),
(1,'2018/01/09',  'click'),
(4,'2018/01/09',  'click'),
(3,'2018/01/12',  'view'),
(4,'2018/01/12',  'transact'),
(3,'2018/01/13',  'view'),
(5,'2018/01/13',  'transact'),
(4,'2018/01/15',  'view'),
(5,'2018/01/15',  'click'),
(4,'2018/01/16',  'view'),
(2,'2018/01/17',  'transact'),
(5,'2018/01/18',  'click');

SELECT ua.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id order by date, action) as ranks
INTO #temp
FROM user_action ua
order by user_id, ranks;

select t1.*, t2.date, t2.action, DATEDIFF(DAY, t2.date, t1.date)
from #temp t1
LEFT JOIN #temp t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t2.action IN ('view','click') and t1.action = 'transact' and (t1.ranks-1) = t2.ranks
order by t1.user_id, t1.ranks;
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!